# How to edit an existing Phonegap project in Dreamweaver 6.0?

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver

I have downloaded a trial of Dreamweaver 6.0 to experiment with PhoneGap.PhoneGap is currently at 2.7.0.

I used Phonegap to create a new project.That was successful:I can compile and run the new project with xcode.

Now,I want to edit the Phonegap app with DW.I found several instructions for DW 5.5 and PhoneGap,But a lot has changed with DW 6.0 without updates to these instructions.For example: the sample code for a DW 5.5 says:

`'<!-- This reference to phonegap.js will allow for code hints as long as the current site has been configured as a mobile application. To configure the site as a mobile application, go to Site -> Mobile Applications -> Configure Application Framework... -->'`.

But I cannot find this option in DW 6.0 anymore.

So my question is,

How do I fully enable (using code hints and such) the editing of an existing Phonegap in DW 6.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

In dreamweaver CS6, click on the Site->PhoneGap Build Service->PhoneGap Build Service and then sign in with your Adobe Id or create if it doesn't exist.
Then it will ask you for the emulators for the platform you want to build your application with.
Then proceed with the project code.

Comment: Although I did not really got the Phonegap Build service working (or actually used it) it said my free trails were over. I got also the feeling that Phonegap support / dev in DW is a bit of a moving target (tutorials about its usage in WM5.5 do no apply to WM6). Disappointing for such an expensive product.
I now use WebStorm for my Phonegap developments.